SVC GAM in the presence of factor variable and transformation of coefficients into relative risk
I would like to get your confirmation on two doubts I have on the application of SVC GAM.
Basically, I would like to know

how to deal with factor variables when predicting spatially varying coefficients as if the factor variable is set to 0 then an error occurs.

if I include a variable in the smooth term alone allowing for SVC in the forms of   s(X, Y, bs = "gp", by = x2) can I transform the coefficient into relative risk by exponentiating them if I fit a Poisson model? Relative risk are easy to interpret.  Should I pass type=response as argument in the predict function to do so? I am not sure as the response is a count ..I think I should exponentiate the output of the predict using link


Hereunder an example
Thank you in advance
Angela
library(mgcv)
library(dplyr)
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)


# Load the North Carolina example dataset
nc=st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# View the first few records of the dataset
head(nc)

# Calculate centroids of the North Carolina counties
nc_centroids=st_centroid(nc)

# Extract the coordinates of centroids
centroids_df=as.data.frame(st_coordinates(nc_centroids))


df=data.frame(n=rpois(100, 5),
              X=centroids_df$X,
              Y=centroids_df$Y,
              x1=rnorm(20,10,3.5),
              x2=rnorm(20,78,6.7),
              x3=rnorm(20,8,2.2),
              x4 = rep(c(1, 2), each = 50))

# Transform x4 into a factor 

df$x4=as.factor(df$x4)


# Add intercept 

df$int=1

# Build a GAM 

gam=gam(n ~ 0 + 
      int   + s(X, Y, bs = 'gp', by = int) + 
      x4 +  # Factor variable 
      x1 +  # x1 added as non smooth term only
      s(X, Y, bs = "gp", by = x2) + # added as smooth term only
      s(X, Y, bs = "gp", by = x3), # added as smooth term only
      family="poisson",  # or negative binomial if data are overdispersed 
      method = "REML",
      data = df)


summary(gam)

# Get spatially varying coefficient for x2
# Set all variables to 0 with the exception of x2 

get_b2=df|> mutate(x2=1,
                   int = 0, 
                   x1=0,
                   x4=0,
                   x3=0)

df=df |> mutate(b1=predict(gam,newdata=get_b2,type="response"))

# When setting the factor variable as 0 the following error pops up 
# Error in `mutate()`:
# ℹ In argument: `b1 = predict(gam, newdata = get_b2)`.
# Caused by error in `X[, pstart[i] - 1 + 1:object$nsdf[i]] <- Xp`:
# ! replacement has length zero

# Second try 

get_b2=df|> mutate(x2=1,
                   int = 0, 
                   x1=0,
                   # x4=0, Do not set to 0 the factor variable 
                   x3=0)

df=df |> mutate(b1=predict(gam,newdata=get_b2, type="response"))

# This works !!! 

# Transform the coeffiecient into Relative Risk for easy interpretation 

head(df)

df$RR=exp(df$b1)

head(df)

